# Playwright and pytest. After the code is executed, one more blank tab is opened

Tags: python, testing, pytest, playwright, playwright-python

A blank tab that doesn't make anything is open. It's waiting for a timeout because it doesn't execute any step. After that, the tab is closed and the test will fail. I have a different file pytest.ini where I defined addopts = --headed --slowmo=1000 --browser=chromium
The second browser is opened for that context.

```
def navigate_to_edit_page():       
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=1000)
            context = browser.new_context(storage_state="playwright/.auth/storage_login.json")
            page = context.new_page()
            BasicAuthentication.execute(page)
  
            page.goto("https://example.org/edit")
            page.locator("input#org_name").fill("This is a test!")
            page.get_by_role("button", name="Save").click()
            expect(page.locator(".notice")).to_have_text("Successful update")
            expect(page).to_have_title("New page")
            context.close()
```

I tried to use other method instead of new page and other staff to improve this function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the context manager into `context.new_page()`?

```
 def navigate_to_edit_page():       
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=1000)
            context = browser.new_context(storage_state="playwright/.auth/storage_login.json")
            with context.new_page () as page:
                BasicAuthentication.execute(page)
  
                page.goto("https://example.org/edit")
                page.locator("input#org_name").fill("This is a test!")
                page.get_by_role("button", name="Save").click()
                expect(page.locator(".notice")).to_have_text("Successful update")
                expect(page).to_have_title("New page")
            context.close()
```

Comment: Yes, it's not working. New because there is a new context, I should use this context, further in my step definition. I'm using BDD with playwright at the same time. The thing is that I have no clue how to do it. Actually I made a function that returns the page, but further, the browser is getting stack and doesn't use JSON file to login.

Answer (score 0):

```
def initialize_page():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context(storage_state="playwright/.auth/storage_login.json")
        page = context.new_page()
        BasicAuthentication.execute(page)
        return page

@given('the edit page of the organization is opened')
def edit_page(my_page):
    my_page = initialize_page()
    my_page.goto("https://example.org/edi")
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this helps solve the problem?